# ionic2 - change font attribute of .loadcontent

Tags: css, angular, ionic2, scss-lint

I am using `LoadingController` to manage the loading page. Below is my code:

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `
       <div padding>
          <div class="loadingheader">processing...</div >
       </div>
        <div>
          <p>
          Verifying your mobile phone number
          </p>
          <p>`+
         " 011 232 43146"
          +
          `
          </p>
          <p>
          Please wait
          </p>
        </div>
      `,
    duration: 100000
  });
```

1. How can I change the font size of `loadheader`? I tried add `css` code in `scss` file of the same page but fail.
2. How to put spinner at the position I wanted? Say I want to put between `loadheader` and my other text. Currently it is at the right of all my text.

Comment: does `.loading-content: { .loadheader: {font-size: 12px !important;}}` work?

Comment: Just tried. Not working

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In order for it to work, you have to add the `css` to `app.scss`:

```
.loading-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  .loadheader{ ///<---my custom class for loading
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```